# tinyMCE v6 event bubbling

Tags: javascript, tinymce, event-bubbling

I trying to catch keydown triggered on < p > element inside of editor iFrame but with this code, i getting textarea element. Event.stopPropagation() does not stop bubbling, i still getting topmost element

```
tinymce.init({
   selector: 'textarea',
   setup:function(editor) {
      editor.on('keydown', function(event) {
         console.log(event.target);
      });
   }
});
```

I see [tinymce.event](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.event/) in API with its own stopPropagation() method but don't get how to make it work. Tinymce.event return undefined same as editor.event or tinymce.Event.type

also, there is [eventDispatcher Utility API](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.util.eventdispatcher/) but trying to process keydown via eventDispatcher.dispatch() triggered inside of editor.on keydown get me nothing

In the end, I tried to remove class/style from a block inside of the editor. And cause this block is added programmatically I cant do this with the class name. I need an element pointer where is keydown happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out that I can use tinyMCE selection helper to get an element with current focus (which triggered an event) and solve my task

So the final code is

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    setup:function(editor) {
       editor.on('keydown', function(event) {
           const element = editor.selection.getNode();
    
           if (editor.dom.hasClass(element, 'classname')) {
    
           }  
       }
});
```